# How do I register my JsonSerializer on Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

Taking the response from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45566139/2968729 I want to add the `NullSerializer` to the autoconfigured `ObjectMapper`. Spring Boot documentation:

> Any beans of type com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module are
>   automatically registered with the auto-configured
>   Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder and are applied to any ObjectMapper
>   instances that it creates. This provides a global mechanism for
>   contributing custom modules when you add new features to your
>   application.

So this is how I'm trying:

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {

    @Bean
    public Module customSerializer() {
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addSerializer(new NullSerializer());
        return module;
    }
}
```

But I'm getting:

```
NullSerializer does not define valid handledType() -- must either register with method that takes type argument or make serializer extend com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer
```

Javadoc of handleType() method says:

> Method for accessing type of Objects this serializer can handle. Note
>   that this information is not guaranteed to be exact -- it may be a
>   more generic (super-type) -- but it should not be incorrect (return a
>   non-related type).
>       Default implementation will return null, which essentially means same as returning Object.class would; that is, that nothing is known
>   about handled type.

Using Spring Boot 2.0.5.RELEASE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're using the raw type. You need to give it a class.

```
module.addSerializer(Object.class, new NullSerializer<>());
```

Comment: That would work for a single class, but I want the serializer to be applied for all objects. The same what was asking the guy from the original question.

Comment: @anat0lius Just give it `Object` then, right? `module.addSerializer(Object.class, new NullSerializer<>());`

Comment: Right! I wrongly was trying `new NullSerializer<>(Object.class)`. Now I'm getting errors from the serializer. The line with `jgen.writeObject(value);` I'm going to see if I can solve it by meself.

Comment: can u help with the serializer code? It doesn't work for me. If the `value = field.get(item)` is not null and try to write it `jgen.writeObject(value)` it fails. Javadoc of the write method says `Method for writing given Java object (POJO) as Json.` but the value is not a POJO  but a simple String (the value of one of the fields of `item`)

Comment: The error is `Can not start an object, expecting field name (context: Object)`

Answer (score 0):

```
you can configure with this method with spring
    

public class TestClass {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(LocalsFinanceCommissionServiceApplication.class, args);
        }
    
        @Bean
        CommandLineRunner sx(ObjectMapper mapper) {
            return args -> {
    
                Map<String, BigDecimal> hello = Map.of("hello", BigDecimal.valueOf(12.11231));
                System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(hello));
//{"hello":12.1123}
            };
        }
    }
    
    class PriceSerializer extends JsonSerializer<BigDecimal> {
        @Override
        public void serialize(BigDecimal value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
            // Using writNumber and removing toString make sure the output is number but not String.
            jgen.writeNumber(value.setScale(4, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
        }
    
        @Override
        public Class<BigDecimal> handledType() {
            return BigDecimal.class;
        }
    }
    
    @Configuration
    class JacksonConfig {
    
        @Bean
        public com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module customSerializer() {
            SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
            module.addSerializer(new PriceSerializer());
            return module;
        }
    }
```